# simulation of this task

Tags: resonance, multisim

Try to make simulation of this task with program of your chose.[image]

Can someone please do this simulation with a program like Multisim and upload the simulation,because i dont have the program.

Comment: Get a simulator and do it yourself is my very strong advice. If you need advice which sim to choose just ask but this then makes it a shopping question and they usually get closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because requesting for tasks to be done is not compatible with a Q and A site.

Comment: Download LTSpice. It's free, good, and is much used by both amateurs and working engineers alike.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you!